# Text that is centered and right-aligned not rendered on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to get text in `center` as well as on the `left` side. If someone can help me rectify the error where I am going wrong ?

Pictorial way to be more precise.

[image: Pictorial way to be more precise.]

Running [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gueqvxua/)

Here's HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="values">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="center-block" style='background:yellow'>
        <div class="text-center">
          <div id="main-text">
            <h3>TEXT</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="side_section">
            <div id="text2" class="pull-right clearfix" style='background:blue'>
              Text2
            </div>

            <div id="text1" class="pull-right clearfix" style='background:blue'>
              Text1
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not use the style attribute because in case of changes in your css file, the style attribute will be applied and not the css in your other file.

Comment: Your description says center and left side but your picture shows center and right side.  Not that it makes much difference, but which one is it that you want?

Comment: @tedmiston oh thanks for that, i need right align

Comment: @xXDarioXx thank you, that is only for the fiddle to know the problem better

Comment: @NewBee Okay, I think my answer below solves your question then.  If it does, feel free to click the checkmark to accept the answer; and if it doesn't, just let me know and I can revise it.

Comment: @NewBee I think you may have changed the answer inadvertently.  You can upvote as many answers as you want, but you can only accept one answer to the question with the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this style :

```
.side_section{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gueqvxua/2/

Comment: thank you for prompt reply.
But in that case, the centered `TEXT` isn't exactly in middle, how about that?

Comment: i do some change check the new jsfiddle link

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for.  The first row demos having left, center, and right aligned text on the same row.  The second row demos just having center and right with a grid offset.

Using grids in Bootstrap (because I saw it in your sample code) is one way to achieve this effect, but there are others too.  If you're not using a framework, you could use CSS floats directly.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <!-- Example 1 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">
      <p>left text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
      <p>center text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
      <p>right text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Example 2 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 text-center">
      <p>center text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
      <p>right text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Example 3 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 text-center">
      <p>center text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
      <span>right 1</span>
      <span>right 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Example 4 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 text-center">
      <p>center text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
      <p style="display: inline;">right 1</p>
      <p style="display: inline;">right 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Example 5 -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4 text-center">
      <p>center text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
      <p class="pull-right">right 2</p>
      <p class="pull-right">right 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Side note: I only used the `xs-*` grid classes because the Stack Overflow snippet renders in such a small window.  The concept works the same with `md-*` or whichever is best for your design.

Comment: if you can help getting two `right text` , `center text` being excatly in the center

Comment: @NewBee I've updated the examples to demonstrate that.  There are a few approaches you can use: #3 - use non block elements, #4 - use `display: inline;` on block elements (like `<p>`), and #5 - use the `pull-right` utility class in Bootstrap.  Note that with #5 the content on top will be pulled right the most, so you might want to reverse the order compared to normal.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#values {
  background: #eee;
}

#values .col-md-10 {
  background: #ddd;
}

#values h3 {
  background: #ccc;
}

#values .list-inline {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid" id="values">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="list-inline pull-right text-right">
        <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Test</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h3 class="text-center">TEXT</h3>
       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS on StackOverflow seems to create an alignment issue, but if you reference a Bootply example using the same code ( http://www.bootply.com/E8fPPsaz25 ) you'll see everything line up nicely.

Comment: thanks for that, but I also need to get the middle text exactly in middle, how can we resolve that?

Comment: You'll have to use `position:absolute` on the `<h3>` tag, see this Bootply Fork: http://www.bootply.com/XuNOdH2kzs